# uname shows uninstalled kernel version

Tags: 14.04, kernel

This is the list of installed kernel versions on my system:

```
bwvdnbro@wixie:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic                         3.13.0-73.116                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic                         3.13.0-74.118                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic                         3.13.0-76.120                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic                         3.13.0-77.121                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic                         3.13.0-79.123                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic                         3.13.0-83.127                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic                         3.13.0-85.129                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic                         3.13.0-86.131                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-87-generic                         3.13.0-87.133                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic                         3.13.0-88.135                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic                         3.13.0-91.138                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic                   3.13.0-73.116                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic                   3.13.0-74.118                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic                   3.13.0-76.120                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic                   3.13.0-77.121                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic                   3.13.0-79.123                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic                   3.13.0-83.127                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic                   3.13.0-85.129                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic                   3.13.0-86.131                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-87-generic                   3.13.0-87.133                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic                   3.13.0-88.135                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic                   3.13.0-91.138                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.91.97                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

However, the output of uname is

```
bwvdnbro@wixie:~$ uname -a
Linux wixie 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As far as I can see, this kernel is not installed. How is this possible? I just rebooted my computer, so the currently running kernel should be the one that was last installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't install it manually, then its package name is `linux-image*`. That's you can't see it in the `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` listing.

1. Check all kernels really exist in `/boot` folder

   ```
   ls -l /boot/
   ```
2. Check its package using

   ```
   dpkg -S /boot/<kernel-filename>
   ```

There are other kernel packages with same version, see [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&section=all&arch=any&keywords=3.16.0-30-generic%20image&searchon=names)